# Maintaining static files

Tags: python, html, django, matplotlib, graphics

In my django framework I collect user input from a form and create a matplotlib image. This image is displayed after a button push in a tagged field in an html file.

After each button push this image is updated, changes and is newly displayed. This works well. Now I intend to introduce a second image at a second tag, that shows up and changes after pressing a different button.

The problem that I have, is that after pushing the second button, the first image disappears and after pushing the first button, the second image disappears. Here is part of the html code:

```
<form method=post action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {% for field in form %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ field.label }}</td>
            <td>{{ field }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <br>
    <p><input type=submit name='button1' value='Create' class="btn btn-default"></form></p>
</form>

<p>
    {% if result != None %}
    {% load static %}
    <img src="{% get_static_prefix %}{{ result }}" width=1000>
    {% endif %}
</p>

<form method="post" class="topright">
    {{form3}}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p><input type=submit name='button2' value='Update' class="btn btn-default" default=1></p>
</form>

<form method=post action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {% for field in form4 %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ field.label }}</td>
            <td>{{ field }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <p><input type=submit name='button3' value='Predict' class="btn btn-default" default=1></p>
</form>

<p>
    {% if predictresult != None %}
    {% load static %}
    <img src="{% get_static_prefix %}{{ predictresult }}" width=1000>
    {% endif %}
</p>
```

The image files are saved via: plt.savefig(plotfile) into the static folder. Most of the views code is the following:

```
def bayes_create_and_update(request):
    #os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    global bandit
    global invgammaresult
    global predictresult
    invgammaresult = None
    predictresult = None
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'button1' in request.POST:
        form = InputForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form2 = form.save(commit=False)
            bandit = gauss_bandit(form2.m, form2.s)
            invgammaresult=pull_and_update(bandit,1)
            invgammaresult=invgammaresult[7:]
            form3= Sample_InputForm()
            form4=Predict_InputForm()


    elif request.method == 'POST' and 'button2' in request.POST:
        form3 = Sample_InputForm(request.POST)
        if form3.is_valid():
            form2 = form3.save(commit=False)
            invgammaresult=pull_and_update(bandit,form2.n)
            invgammaresult=invgammaresult[7:]
            form = InputForm(request.POST)
            form4=Predict_InputForm()

    elif request.method == 'POST' and 'button3' in request.POST:
        form4 = Predict_InputForm(request.POST)
        if form4.is_valid():
            form2 = form4.save(commit=False)
            predictresult=bandit.predict(form2.p1,form2.p2)
            predictresult=predictresult[7:]
            form = InputForm(request.POST)
            form3= Sample_InputForm()
    else:
        form = InputForm()
        form3= Sample_InputForm()
        form4=Predict_InputForm

    return render ( request, 'C:/Users/Jan/PycharmProjects/Newversion/newattempt/online_comp/templates/bayes/bayes.html',
            {'form': form,
             'result': invgammaresult,
             'form3':form3,
             'form4':form4,
             'predictresult':predictresult
             })
```

and my models that give rise to the form is this code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm


class Input(models.Model):
    m = models.FloatField(
        verbose_name=' Mean of the Normal Distribution:', default=0.0)
    s = models.FloatField(
        verbose_name=' Standard Deviation of the Normal Distribution:', default=1.0)

class InputForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Input
        fields='__all__'

class Sample_Input(models.Model):
    n = models.FloatField(
        verbose_name=' Number of samples you wish to draw:', default=1)

class Sample_InputForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Sample_Input
        fields='__all__'

class Predict_Input(models.Model):
    p1 = models.FloatField(
        verbose_name=' Lower bound', default=-1.0)
    p2 = models.FloatField(
        verbose_name=' Upper bound', default=1.0)

class Predict_InputForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Predict_Input
        fields='__all__'
```

Thx

Comment: Aren't you missing closing form tag of the first form or its a typo?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. In line 13, there is a </form> closing the first form

Comment: Ok you edited your Q, based on my edit feedback. It was typo earlier, got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by creating two sub directories in the static folder and changing the path of saving the file in the compute file (not shown above). So the image output of both functions wouldn't interfere with each other.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be helpful if you posted your view as well as the source for the forms you are putting into your html. One possibility is that you have the request.POST info switched in the views but would need to see.

Small detail but form method=post should be form method="post" everywhere correct?